# remotely connect to files via gs path

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm using an R package that requires a list of file locations to work. Normally, if I have files stored in remote servers I provide the ftp, http or ssh paths and it works. If I do the same providing the gs path it doesn't work.

I cannot introduce gsutil commands in the list I provide or modify the code. I also cannot copy the files stored in the cloud in a local server because the space is not enough. I only need to use the files remotely stored in gcloud and pass them to the tool I'm using. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible to open/edit the files stored on Google Cloud Storage (GCS), GCS is a kind of immutable storage and when you update a file on that service you are overwriting the existing file.

GCS doesn't offer the alternative to open and edit files on the fly like Google Drive, for this reason you need to download your files to work with them.

In this [video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/gcp-fundamentals/google-cloud-storage-HLKXf) is explained why you can't edit files on fly.

Comment: Thank you for your help